# Появление блока на странице через определенное время и определенное количество раз

Tags: javascript, cookie

Нужно, чтобы зашедшему на сайт человеку через 10 секунд показывался блок с подсказкой. через 20 секунд или по нажатию на крестик блок закрывался сам.

Через рандомное количество времени появился снова, и так 10 раз за день не более. Даже если человек покинул страницу и потом вернулся работа скрипта продолжилась. Я решил все это сделать через куки, но запутался сильно...

Помогите пожалуйста.

Мой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ceckf();
});

var infoblock_cookie_dead = "infoblock_cookie_dead"; // делаем куку  
var infoblock_cookie_count_view = "infoblock_count_view977"; // делаем куку  
var infoblock = document.getElementById("infoblock"); //Выбираем картинку

var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); // устанавливаем время жизни куки для подсчета показов
t = d.setTime(d.getTime()); // для рандомного показа времени.

var randtime = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000+1); // генерируем количество секунд сколько будет жить кука от 1 до 1000 секунд

time_dead_cookie = t + (randtime*1000); // текущее время + случаное количество секунд от 1 до 1000

// функция проверки
function ceckf() {

    if(!getCookie(infoblock_cookie_dead) && getCookie(infoblock_cookie_count_view) <= 10) { // проверяем наличие куки

        viewblock();

    } 

}

function viewblock() {

    setTimeout(function(){

        infoblock.style.display = "block"; // показываем

        //document.cookie = ""+ infoblock_cookie_dead + "=1;expires="+time_dead_cookie+"; path='/'"; // записываем куку для показа через рандомное время показать блок

        if(!getCookie(infoblock_cookie_count_view)) {
            document.cookie = ""+ infoblock_cookie_count_view + "=1;expires="+d.toUTCString()+"; path='/'";
        } else {
            document.cookie = ""+ infoblock_cookie_count_view + "=2;expires="+d.toUTCString()+"; path='/'";
        }
        setTimeout(function(){

            infoblock.style.display = "none"; // проявляем

            ceckf();

        },20000); // 20000 = 20 секунд, вермя через которое закроется окно

        $(".infoblock-close").click(function(){  infoblock.style.display = "none"; ceckf(); }); // закрываем по клику

    },10000); // через сколько покажется блок после открытия страниц 10000 = 10 секундам
}   


// выводим куку
function getCookie(name) 
{
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
        "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : false;
}
```

Comment: Это аналог вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440598/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-modal-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-24-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Например можно сделать так:

```
// расписание показов
var schedule = [],

    // функция, которую будем запускать по расписанию
    callback = function(){ alert(123); };

// срабатывает на таймер и запускает следующую итерацию
function call() {

    // проверяем, определена ли функция, которую нужно запускать
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        // если да, запускаем...
        callback();
    }

    // снова запускаем таймер по расписанию, пока оно есть
    if (schedule.length > 0) {
        run();
    }
}

// функция читает расписание и запускает таймер
function run() {
    // вырежем первый элемент из расписания в эту переменную
    var current = schedule.shift();

    // если текущий элемент расписания указан в виде массива
    if (current instanceof Array) {
        // тогда генерируем случайное число
        current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (current[1] - current[0] + 1)) + current[0];
    }

    // в итоге, если есть число
    if (typeof current === "number") {
        // значит запускаем таймер с такой задержкой
        setTimeout(call, current * 1000);
    }
}

// первый запуск через 10 сек.
schedule.push(10),

// второй, в случайном промежутке между 5 и 10 минутами
schedule.push([300, 600]),

// третий...
schedule.push([800, 1000])

// и так далее...

// запускаем таймер
run();
```

Расписание предлогаю хранить либо в куках, либо в localStorage. Соотвественно, перед запуском скрипта расписание нужно прочитать из локального хранилища или кук и при изменении записывать обратно