# Как показывать Pop-Up только раз в день?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.
У меня есть `Pop-Up`. Мне нужно чтобы он появлялся для каждого отдельного юзера только раз в день. Я знаю что нужно использовать `cookies` но т.к. я не очень силен в [js](/questions/tagged/js) мне нужно пошаговое руководство как это сделать.

То ли я плохо искал, то ли действительно нет нормального и главное правильного решения этой задачи. Кому не сложно, помогите [Вот ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/g6kto03y/)!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divPopUp = $('.popup'); 
  setTimeout(function () {
        divPopUp.fadeIn();
    }, 1000);
  $('.close-popup').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    divPopUp.fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: Используйте AJAX, так будет очень удобней, если ваш пользователь только авторизирован, если нет, то куки вам не помогут, т.к. кто-то их может стереть, тогда нужно юзать плагин проверки ИД браузера + AJAX и проверять получал ли этот браузер месседж или нет.

Comment: Что-то вроде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440607/186083

Comment: "раз в день" - слишком расплывчато. Если пользователь зашел на страницу вечером (в каком часовом поясе, пользовательском или серверном?), а потом на следующий день утром - должен опять показываться popup?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем ajax?... Куки можно на стороне сервера проверять и задавать.
Вот пример который проверяет куку и если ее нет он выведет скрипт показа модалки и установит куку которая потом автоматом удалится через сутки. Но если кука есть то скрипт js просто не покажет popup.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['SHOW_MODAL'])){?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var divPopUp = $('.popup');
            setTimeout(function () {
                divPopUp.fadeIn();
            }, 1000);
            $('.close-popup').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                divPopUp.fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
<?
    setCookie('SHOW_MODAL', 'Y', time() + 86400, '/'); // Установим куку SHOW_MODAL значение Y на сутки для всех страниц сайта.
}
?>
```

Comment: Можете сказать после первого раза как показывать будет через еще один день

Comment: Смотрите. Этот скрипт проверяет есть ли куки с названием "SHOW_MODAL" на клиенте. Если куки есть, то js который показывает popup `divPopUp.fadeIn();` Просто не будет выведен и popup показан не будет, в ином случае выведется js скрипт и установится кука "SHOW_MODAL" время жизни куки 86400 секунд, это один день, после кука удалится браузером. Поскольку через день после показа popup, браузер удалит куку, то popup опять будет показан.

Comment: это значит для каждого человека один раз, а не раз в день. как сказал автор `Как показывать Pop-Up только раз в день?`

Comment: Нет это значит для каждого человека один раз в день, так как куки устанавливаются для браузера. Время жизни куки 1день, пока есть эта кука сообщение показано не будет, потом браузер удалит куку (через день) И сообщение снова будет показано и кука будет задана.

Comment: Извини на это не обратил внимания)))